# Prove that $\langle n|\rho|m\rangle \langle m|\rho|n\rangle \leq \langle n|\rho|n\rangle\langle m|\rho|m\rangle $ for any density matrix $\rho$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

I couldn't find my answer in the questions so I ask it here.

If $\rho$ is a density matrix then I'd like to prove the following :

$\langle n|\rho|m\rangle \langle m|\rho|n\rangle \ \leq \ \langle n|\rho|n\rangle\langle m|\rho|m\rangle $

the $m$ and $n$ kets are some vector in Hilbert space.

Any idea?

Comment: Positivity of the 2x2 submatrix? But I guess this falls under the homework policy.

Comment: Have you tried applying Cauchy-Schwartz-Bunyakowski  to $|n\rangle$ and $\rho |m\rangle$?

Comment: @mikestone Schwarz.  (And it only works with the square root - positivity of $\rho$ is essential, otherwise it does not work, see my above comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Let $ \vert u\rangle = \sqrt{\rho}\vert m\rangle$ and $ \vert v\rangle = \sqrt{\rho}\vert n\rangle$.

Your statement is equivalent to

$$|\langle u\vert v \rangle|^2 \leq \langle u\vert u\rangle.\langle v\vert v\rangle$$

Comment: Given that $\rho$ is a matrix what sense do you give to $\sqrt{\rho}$?

Comment: @ZerTheHero Doesn't a density matrix have positive eigenvalues? If so, it has a matrix square root.

Comment: Since $\rho$ is positive semidefinite, there is a unique square root. See for example the presentation here - https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00207390500285867

Comment: @mikestone yes.  I suppose I was suggesting something a little more explicit... along the lines of your reply or the reply of rnva.

Comment: @rnva There is a unique *positive* square root.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, a unique positive *semidefinite* square root.